# float and subfig package interference: subfigures with exact placement

Tags: floats, captions, subfloats

I'm using the `subfig` package for subfigures and the `float` package for forced float placement (`H`). Using both these packages results in the subcaption not getting reset. The following example shows six figures from (a) to (f), whereas I'd expect them to be from (a) to (c), twice.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H] \centering
    \subfloat[first subfig]{\includegraphics{img}}
    \subfloat[second subfig]{\includegraphics{img}}
    \subfloat[third subfig]{\includegraphics{img}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H] \centering
    \subfloat[first subfig]{\includegraphics{img}}
    \subfloat[second subfig]{\includegraphics{img}}
    \subfloat[third subfig]{\includegraphics{img}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is subfigures exactly where I want them to be. Is there a way to solve this interference, or is there a better solution?

Comment: +1. The thing that was problem for you has actually solved my purpose exactly the way I desired. Thanks for asking this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the `\caption` command that resets the subfigure numbers and you don't provide one.

Actually, `\caption` performs `\stepcounter{figure}` and it's this command that does the business. So, if you really don't want to have a global caption, issue

```
\stepcounter{figure}\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
```

before `\end{figure}`. This will reset the `subfloat` counter but won't affect the `figure` counter, as the net change is 0.

Answer (score 3):

Put

```
\setcounter{subfigure}{0}
```

in between the two figures.

Answer (score 2):

The `\subfloat` command is designed to work with `\caption` only. If you don't want a `\caption` inside your figures, use `\phantomcaption` instead. This will both increase the `figure` counter and give proper hyperlinks when the `hyperref` package will be used. (`\phantomcaption` needs caption v3.2 or newer)